# Visual Studios 2012 RGB cube displaying black cube

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, rgb

I'm just starting out using visual studios and C++ and I've been following along the examples in Ed Angel's Interactive Computer Graphics book. I've seem to come into a snag with the rotating RGB cube example. I followed along exactly and I have got it to run and display a cube but the cube is all black instead of colored. To my understanding everything is correct and I have haven't been able to find any suggestions or hints as to what went wrong from google searches. I was wondering if anyone here with much more experience than I have could help me figure out what happened or point me in the direction.

```
// Display a rotating color cube

#include "Angel.h"

typedef Angel::vec4 color4;
typedef Angel::vec4 point4;

const int NumVertices = 36;


point4 points[NumVertices];
color4 colors[NumVertices];

//Vertices of a unit cube centered at origin, sides aligned with axes
point4 vertices[8] = {
    point4( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
    point4( -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
    point4( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
    point4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
    point4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0),
    point4( -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 1.0),
    point4( 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 1.0),
    point4( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0)
};

//RGBA colors
color4 vertex_colors[8] = {
    color4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  //black
    color4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),  //red
    color4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  //yellow
    color4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),  //blue
    color4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  //green
    color4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  //magenta
    color4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),  //white
    color4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)  //cyan
};

//Array of rotation angles (in degrees) for each coordinate axis
enum { Xaxis = 0, Yaxis = 1, Zaxis = 2, NumAxes = 3 };
int Axis = Xaxis;
GLfloat Theta[NumAxes] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

GLuint theta; //The location of the "theta" shader uniform variable
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//quad generates two triangles for each face and assigns colors to the vertices

int Index = 0;
void
quad( int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[a]; points[Index] = vertices[a]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[b]; points[Index] = vertices[b]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[c]; points[Index] = vertices[c]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[a]; points[Index] = vertices[a]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[c]; points[Index] = vertices[c]; Index++;
    colors[Index] = vertex_colors[d]; points[Index] = vertices[d]; Index++;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//generate 12 triangles: 36 vertices and 36 colors
void
colorcube( void )
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2);
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6);
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7);
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2);
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7);
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//OpenGL initialization
void
init( void )
{
    colorcube();

    //Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    //Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points) + sizeof(colors), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(points), points );
    glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), sizeof(colors), colors );

    //Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader36.glsl", "fshader36.glsl" );
    std::cout << "Program ID:" <<program;
    glUseProgram ( program );

    //set up vertex arrays
    GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
    glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(points)) );

    theta = glGetUniformLocation( program, "theta" );

    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
display( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glUniform3fv( theta, 1, Theta );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch ( key ) {
    case 033:
    case 'q': case 'Q':
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        break;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
mouse( int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
    if ( state == GLUT_DOWN ) {
        switch( button ) {
            case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON: Axis = Xaxis; break;
            case GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON: Axis = Yaxis; break;
            case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON: Axis = Zaxis; break;
        }
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
idle( void )
{
    Theta[Axis] += 0.01;

    if ( Theta[Axis] > 360.0 ) {
        Theta[Axis] -= 360.0;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );

    glutCreateWindow( "Color Cube" );

    glewInit();

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
    glutMouseFunc( mouse );
    glutIdleFunc( idle );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

fshader36.glsl

```
#version 150

in  vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;

void main() 
{ 
    fColor = color;
}
```

vshader36.glsl

```
#version 150

in  vec4 vPosition;
in  vec4 vColor;
out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 theta;

void main() 
{

    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  c.x,  -s.x, 0.0,
            0.0, s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, s.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            -s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, -s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    color = vColor;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually set vColor for it to have a valid value. Do the same thing that you did to set vPosition:

```
GLuint vColor= glGetAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( vColor);
glVertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(colors)) );
```

Comment: thank you very much, I must've missed that when reading through.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually pass any colour information to your shader.